# Samsung is making an ASIC to mine bitcoin and ether so is GPU-mining of ether going to be non profitable?

Tags: ether, mining, gpu

Ethereum PoW is designed to be ASIC-resistant but Samsung is making an ASIC to mine bitcoin and ether so is GPU-mining going to be non profitable?

https://techcrunch.com/2018/01/31/samsung-confirms-asic-chips/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, it's impossible to make an "ASIC to mine bitcoin and ether", because an ASIC that was made to mine both would be horribly inefficient at both, since the mining algorithms are so different.

It's hard to say realy. GPU-mining is already non profitable for Bitcoin, but obviously is the most profitable type of mining for Ethereum. Samsung has released very little information. In my opinion, it's unlikely that any ASICs that Samsung develops for Ethereum mining would be much more than a specialized GPU anyway. Add to this that Ethereum is most likely going to be abandoning PoW based consensus in favor of PoS based consensus within the next 2 years, it's a moot conversation really.

Answer (score 0):

ETHash algorithm for ethereum is memory hard so samsung would have to develope something which also has RAM minimum of 4 GB
also i dont even know if ASICS with RAM is even possible

As the previous answer it seems like a huge move to manufacture something for Ethereum when we already know that its moving away from mining and on to proof of stake